# Cyclomatic complexity plugin for java in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am working with Jenkins. And my project is in java so  I have installed PMD plugin to calculate Cyclomatic complexity of our project.

I have also configured PMD with post build action. Command which I have used is pmd:pmd, pmd:cpd. and after building I am getting the output like 
1.Import Statements
2.Unnecessary
3.Unused Code

but I also want cyclomatic complexity by using PMD. How can I get cyclomatic complexity by using PMD. I have been struggling from last 2 weeks.

Comment: Is PMD mandatory? [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_metrics.html#CyclomaticComplexity) also calculate cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: No, PMD is not mandatory. I was getting other results by PMD and I don't want different plugin to be installed only for cyclomatic complexity. That's the reason my first preference was PMD. If  cyclomatic complexity can be done by Checkstyle. Please tell the way how to do that in jenkins.

Comment: Do you use some tool (like Maven) to generate your build?

Comment: Yes, I am sing Maven.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure [PMD](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/usage.html) and [Checkstyle](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/usage.html) plugins on your `pom.xml` in order to get your current PMD reports as well as cyclomatic complexity from Checkstyle.

The report is built with one single step:

```
mvn clean site
```

The file `target/site/index.html` points to the index of the generated docs and reports.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `checkstyle` [CyclomaticComplexity](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_metrics.html#CyclomaticComplexity) plugin can do the job.

You may configure the `checkstyle` `CyclomaticComplexity` check in your maven `pom.xml` file or gradle config file, and `Jenkins` will call it automatically.